# If $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ is such that $f(x) \leq 2 \int_0^x f(t) dt$, show that $f(x)=0$ on its domain

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality

From an SNS exam:

> Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f(x) \leq 2 \int_0^x f(t) dt$. How can I show that $f(x)$ is identically $0$ in its domain?

My attempt: for every $t$ in $[0,1]$ consider $x_{max,t}$ such that the maximum value of $f$ in $[0,t]$ if $f(x_{max,t})$. Now, for the geometric meaning of the integral, $\int_0^t f(x)dx \leq x_{max}$ so $f(t) \leq 2x_{max,t}$. How can I conclude?

Comment: Is $f$ continuous.

Comment: Do you need to show that $f$ **has** a zero (i.e., there exists $x \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x)=0$, or that $f$ is **identically** zero (i.e., for all $x \in [0,1]$, $f(x)=0$?  Without quantifiers, it's hard for me to interpret your question.

Comment: The keyword here is *Grönwall's inequality*. It has probably been discussed on this site before.

Comment: identically zero, sorry

Comment: Here is an idea. Define the set $\mathscr{I}$ of the points $x \in [0. 1]$ such that the result is true on the interval $[0, x].$ Show $\mathscr{I} \neq \varnothing$ and that $1 = \sup \mathscr{I} \in \mathscr{I}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is a special case of [Grönwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality#Integral_form_for_continuous_functions). One can proceed directly as follows:

Define $g:[0, 1] \to \Bbb R$ as
$$
 g(x) = e^{-2x} \int_0^x f(t) \, dt \, .
$$
Then  $g$ is non-negative with $g(0) = 0$ and *decreasing:*
$$
 g'(x) = e^{-2x} \left( f(x) - 2 \int_0^x f(t) \, dt \right) \le 0 \, .
$$
It follows that $g$ (and consequently $f$) is identically zero
on the interval.

Note that the upper bound for $f$ is not needed for this conclusion, only the
non-negativity.

Comment: To evaluate $g'$ you use FTC and thus continuity of $f$ is used implicitly. But +1 for the trick of multiplication by the exponential factor.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: As I understand it from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Equivalent_definitions, if $f$ is Lebesgue integrable then $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) dt$ is absolutely continuous and differentiable almost everywhere, with $F'(x) = f(x)$. Then $g$ is absolutely continuous with $g'(x) \le 0$ a.e., and therefore decreasing.

Answer (score 6):

One way to proceed is to iterate the inequality.

Note that since $f(t) \leq 1$, we have that
$$ f(x) \leq 2 \int_0^x 1 dt = \frac{2^1}{1!}x = 2x.$$
Thus
$$ f(x) \leq 2 \int_0^x 2t dt = \frac{2^2}{2!}x^2 = 2x^2.$$
Iterating again shows that
$$ f(x) \leq \frac{2^3}{3!} x^3 = \frac{4}{3} x^3,$$
and more generally that
$$ f(x) \leq \frac{2^n}{n!} x^n$$
for any $n \geq 1$.

But for any $x \in [0,1]$, this tends to $0$.

Comment: This does not use any assumption of continuity of $f$ like the other answer implicitly does. +1

Answer (score -1):

**hint**

We have that $$\forall x,X\in[0,1]$$

$$0\le f(x)\le 1$$

and

$$f(X)\le 2\int_0^Xf(t)dt$$

if $X=x=0$ we find that

$$0\le f(0)\le 2\times 0$$