# Functional inequality with integral function

Tags: calculus, integral-inequality, functional-inequalities

Given a function  $f:[0;1]\to[0;1]$ such that $f(x)\leq2\int_0^x f(t)dt$, prove that $f(x)=0$    $
 \forall x\in [0;1]$.

I've observed that the function has to be concave down in his domain and that $f(0)=0$, but nothing more.

Comment: Because $0 \leq f(x) \leq 1,$ can we conclude that $f(x) \leq 2x$? From that, can we conclude $f(x) \leq 2x^2$? What happens when we iterate this logic?

Comment: How do we know that $0 \leq f(x) \leq 1$, and how does that imply that $f(x) \leq 2x$?

Comment: @cpiegore see my answer.

Comment: $0 \leq f(x) \leq 1$ by definition: look at the range

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ is such that $f(x) \leq 2 \int_0^x f(t) dt$, show that $f(x)=0$ on its domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3019119/if-f0-1-to0-1-is-such-that-fx-leq-2-int-0x-ft-dt-show-that-fx) – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(x)%5Cleq2%5Cint_0%5Ex%20f(t)dt%24)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answer by Meowdog is much nicer for continuous $f,$ but this is how I would approach the problem for a general $f.$

Let's begin by proving that $f(x) \leq \frac{2^{n}x^n}{n!}$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ and all whole numbers $n.$

By the definition of $f,$ we have that $f(x) \leq 1$ for all $x,$ so the base case for $n = 0$ is true. Now, given that $f(x) \leq \frac{2^{k}x^k}{k!},$ we have that $$f(x) \leq 2\int_0^x f(t) dt \leq 2 \int_0^x \frac{2^{k}t^k}{k!} dt = \frac{2^{k+1}x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$$

so by induction our hypothesis is proven.

So, because $0$ is the infimum of the sequence $f_n(x) = \frac{2^{n}x^n}{n!}$ for all $x \in [0,1],$ we must have $f(x) \leq 0,$ so we have $0 \leq f(x) \leq 0 \Rightarrow f(x) = 0.$

Comment: I think that yours is nicer, though. Mine needs continuity.

Comment: @Meowdog I missed at a first glance that yours required continuity (for FTC) so on that realization I do prefer mine for practical reasons, but I still certainly appreciate your answer, it works out quite beautifully

Comment: Thank you. So does yours.

Answer (score 4):

We must assume that $f$ is continuous of course (**SO CAUTION**).

Set
$$
g(x) := \exp\left(-2 x \right)\int^x_0 2f(t)~\mathrm{d}t.
$$
It follows that
$$
g'(x) = 2\exp(-2x)\left( \underbrace{-\int^x_0 2f(t)~\mathrm{d}t +f(x)}_{\leq 0} \right) \leq 0 .
$$
So $g$ is decreasing. Since $g(0) = 0$, we have
$$
\exp(-2x)\int^x_0 2f(t)~\mathrm{d}t~\leq 0
$$
for all $x \in [0, 1]$ and therefore
$$
\int^x_0 2f(t)~\mathrm{d}t~\leq 0
$$
for all $x \in [0, 1]$. In total:
$$
0 \leq f(x) \leq \int^x_0 2f(t)~\mathrm{d}t \leq 0
$$
on $[0, 1]$.

This yields $f(x) = 0$ as desired.
The keyword "Gronwall lemma" is also worth researching.

Comment: Do we actually have to assume $f$ is continuous? I don't see where that appears in my approach

Comment: Exactly. I need it, you don't. I wanted to show this, because it's closely related to Gronwall's Lemma, which I think might be important for @Federico A to learn about.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, it suffices that $f$ is (Lebesgue) integrable, see my comment here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3019119/if-f0-1-to0-1-is-such-that-fx-leq-2-int-0x-ft-dt-show-that-fx#comment9374070_3019719

Comment: Ah okay, I see... . So should work, yes. Have not thought about it that way, but thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using @Stephen Donovan 's idea we have that since the function is continuous, for all $x$ we have that
$$\int_0^xf(t)\,dt=x\cdot f(c)\qquad \text{for some }c\in[0,x]$$
But since the range of $f$ is $[0,1]$, we have that $0\leq f(c)\leq 1$ and hence
$$f(x)\leq 2x\cdot f(c)\leq 2x.$$
From here we do a bootstrap-type argument, we insert this inequality back in the original one obtaining
$$f(x)\leq 2\int_0^xf(t)\,dt\leq 2 \int_0^x2t\,dt=2x^2$$
and iterating this procedure we obtain that
$$f(x)\leq \frac{2^{n}}{n!}\cdot x^n\quad \forall n\geq 1\qquad \overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\qquad f(x)\equiv 0\qquad \forall x\in[0,1].$$